# Send variable to controller through url MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I need that this url "Home/Details/123" show a page Details with the details of the item with id 123, how can I do this? I think that the route have to be registered but I need more information about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `Home` controller, Create an action method with name `Details` which has an `int` parameter with name `id`

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult Details(int id)
   {
     //get the item from the id and return the view
     Customer customerModel=repositary.GetCustomerFromId(id);
     return View(customerModel);
   }
}
```

Assuming that `repositary.GetCustomerFromId` method returns an object of `Customer` class and your Details view is strongly typed to Customer class.

```
@model Customer
<h2>@Model.FirstName</h2>
<p>@Model.AddressLine1</p>
```

Your default route definition, in global.asax is enough.